# Every finite group of square-free order is soluble

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Prove that every finite group whose order is square free is soluble.

I think it is enough to show that every sylow subgroup of this is cyclic.

Please tell me if my idea is right and if it is wrong please give me a little help,thanks.

Comment: It's clear that every Sylow subgroup is cyclic, but the result doesn't follow immediately from that step. Induct on the order of the group and use the fact that $G$ is solvable if $N$ and $G/N$ are solvable for some normal $N\subset G$.

Comment: That they're cyclic is immediate. What's your rationale from there?

Comment: It is actually enough that all Sylow subgroups are cyclic, but you need some non-trivial group theory to prove that (transfer theorems or normal $p$-complement theorems).

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be a finite group of square-free order and let $p$ be the smallest prime divisor of $|G|$, with $P$ being a Sylow $p$-subgroup of G. Then $P$ is cyclic, solvable, and has a normal complement $K$ in $G$ (Burnside 1900). Then $|K|$ is square-free, and, by induction on the order of the group, $K$ is solvable. Also, $G/K \cong P$ is solvable, so $G$ is, as a solvable extension also solvable.

Reference: Theorem 17 [here](https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1121&context=rhumj).