# Solvability of group of order $pqrs$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $p,q,r,s$ are distinct primes,and $G$ is a group of order $pqrs$,then is $G$ solvable ?

Comment: Yes. There might be an elementary argument, but it follows from Burnside's transfer theorem that it is in fact supersolvable (as is any group of squarefree order).

Comment: Yes, see the question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997072/every-finite-group-of-square-free-order-is-soluble). As Robinson says in the comment, the proof will need some non-trivial group theory.